# Using Github REST API

Tags: rest, github

Hello I am a beginner at using the github rest api and I am trying to use the next endpoint:
https://api.github.com/projects/PROJECT_ID

The documentation I am following is(https://docs.github.com/en/rest/projects/projects?apiVersion=2022-11-28#get-a-project)

I have verified with other endpoints that auth is not a problem and since I am just testing I am using curl to perform the calls.

My question is where can I find the PROJECT_ID number? to then replace it in the URL.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the GET all projects endpoint to find the id.

```bash
curl -L \
  -H "Accept: application/vnd.github+json" \
  -H "Authorization: Bearer <YOUR-TOKEN>" \
  -H "X-GitHub-Api-Version: 2022-11-28" \
  https://api.github.com/orgs/ORG/projects
```

Comment: Hello Jeremy thank you for answering ! I may be incorrect but I have no organization in my github account I basically clicked the project option and created one.

I even have projects that are not linked at all with repos, they are standalone projects. My question is in order to enlist them with the API do I need to add them to an organization?